Disruption of the whole app when labels are placed in the Frame
I have the code below, where I have my labels placed in the Tkinter root.
It is exactly how I want my app to look, but I would like to have the labels on the top of my left Frame.
However, when I place the label location from root to Frame.
The look much smaller, and my frames disappear (at least that is what I can see).
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.maxsize(1500, 1000)
root.config(bg="blue")

################ RIGHT FRAME ########################################
right_frame=Frame(root, width= 230, height=700, borderwidth=5, relief=GROOVE)
right_frame.grid(row=0, column=200, padx=10, pady=5)


################ RIGHT FRAME ########################################
left_frame=Frame(root, width=600, height=700, borderwidth= 5, relief= GROOVE)
left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)


sending_To= Label(root, text= 'To: ')
sending_To.grid(row=0, column=0)
sending_field=Entry(root, width=50)

in_Copy= Label(root, text= 'Cc: ')
in_Copy.grid(row=0, column=0)

subject= Label(root, text= 'Subject: ')
subject.grid()

root.mainloop()


Which one left or right frame?

The width= and height= options of a Frame normally only apply when it is empty.  When you add any widgets to it, it will automatically resize itself to fit those widgets - so what you're seeing is Tkinter behaving exactly as it was designed to.  If you really want to just waste the rest of the space in the Frame, you can call .grid_propagate(False) or .pack_propagate(False) (whichever matches the geometry manager used to add the widgets) on the Frame.

@jasonharper Thank you so much -  that hugely helped. I did not see this comment .

Replace root with left_frame
The row and column isn't layout properly.
Change this:
right_frame.grid(row=0, column=200, padx=10, pady=5)

To:
right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)# column =1 not 200

snippet:
sending_To= Label(left_frame, text= 'To: ')
sending_To.grid(row=0, column=0)
sending_field=Entry(left_frame, width=50)
sending_field.grid(row=0, column=1)

in_Copy= Label(left_frame, text= 'Cc: ')
in_Copy.grid(row=1, column=0)

subject= Label(left_frame, text= 'Subject: ')
subject.grid(row=2, column=0)

Screenshot:


this nearly it. However, my left frame does not have the right size anymore.  I blue all around it and I want it to be on the top

Add keyword sticky to left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='n') # Add sticky
